# onblur and onclick in at a time in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a case where on a page there is a input field and a button to next page.

Now if onblur event is called on an input, the data should get saved and onclick of button the page should redirect to next page with the latest data from this page.

if the user types in input and directly hits the button, both the events are called at the same time and the latest data is not saved.

is there a design pattern or a common solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you make a working snippet using `<>` to demonstrate your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** You should disable the button while the data is being saved. Also don't forget to have an indicator somewhere to let the user know the data is being saved and that is why they can't go to the next page.

**Solution 2:** When the user clicks, you check if the data has been saved. If it hasnt been saved, you save it then redirect once it has been saved.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the **demo** shown below

```js
var input1 = document.querySelector( "#inp1" );
var button = document.querySelector( "button" );
var button2 = document.querySelector( "input[type='button']" );

button.addEventListener( "click", () => console.log( "click" ) );
button2.addEventListener( "click", () => console.log( "click2" ) );
input1.addEventListener( "blur", () => console.log( "blur" ) );
input1.addEventListener( "change", () => console.log( "change" ) );
```

```html
<input id="inp1"><br><br><br><button>Check</button><br><br><br><input type="button" value="Check 2">
```

`blur` event is being fired before `click` event, however `change` event is being fired before `blur` event itself - regardless of which **button** (`input` or `button`) is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
onkeyup="myFunction()"
```

as an event listener